# How to upgrade Server 2012 to 2016 with TFS 2017 and SQL Server installed

Tags: windows-server-2012, alm, windows-server-2016

We are running TFS 2017 on a single server with the following setup:

- Windows Server 2012
- SQL Server 2016 (only for TFS databases)
- TFS 2017
- Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (for running builds from TFS)
- Some other applications lik NodeJs, Crystal Reports, Sandcastle Help File Builder which are needed to build our projects

For many reasons we would like to upgrade this server to a new setup like this:

- Windows Server 2016
- SQL Server 2016 (only thing good in the old setup)
- TFS 2018
- Visual Studio 2017

The main reason is we can not build C# 7 code on the current setup. But we also need to stay within the supported upgrade paths for all out software. Since Visual Studio 2017 needs Server 2012r2 or higher, the first thing we need to do is get on a new OS. But since put so much effort in this box, we prefer an inplace upgrade, so that we can do an inplace upgrade on TFS 2017 afterwards. One other concern is that we would like to keep our Netbiosname the same so we have zero configuration overhead on developer workstations.

Does anybody have any experience with such an upgrade, or are there other recommended steps we need to take to get this thing done?

Comment: Although upgrading is never a bad thing, I'm confused by the statement *The main reason is we can not build C# 7 code on the current setup*. Your version of TFS has nothing to do with your build server. If you're running build on your TFS app tier or data tier, **that** is a big problem; you should set up a separate build server.

Comment: @DanielMann I guess you are right that it was a bad decision to let our TFS also act as a build agent. But besides that we also want to stay up to date with our software... But i think our first step is to move the build agent to another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is building project with VS 2017 in TFS build, a simple way is  [deploying a build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) on a machine that meets VS installation requirement.

If you want to have a total in place upgrade, consider doing a [dry run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018) of your upgrade in a pre-production environment.

> You need to go through article [Upgrade your deployment to the latest
>   version of TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started) before doing upgrade. And follow the steps in
>   article [Upgrade scenario walkthrough for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough)
>   to upgrade your TFS. Summarize the steps here:
>
> 1. **Prepare your environment**. The first step is to check the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) for TFS 2018. Upgrade SQL Server is
>      necessary for your scenario. Including SQL Server, you also need to check other system
>      requirements and prepare the environment.
> 2. **Expect the best, prepare for the worst**. You must have a complete and consistent set of [database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan) in case something
>      goes wrong.
> 3. **Do the upgrade**. Once the preparation is done, you'll need to install the new version of TFS to get new binaries, and then run
>      through the upgrade wizard to upgrade your databases.
> 4. **Configure new features**. Depending on what version you upgraded from, you may need to [configure each team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) to gain access
>      to some of the new features made available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know it's better for us to run the build agent on a seperate machine. But besides that we also want to stay up to date with our software. The thing is that the docs do not describe a scenario that also upgrades the OS. I guess i just have to find out myself, and go crazy on a temporary clone of the VM...

Comment: Upgrade OS is also a part a upgrade. You could try to doing a dry run first as I mentioned.